Which natural deduction rule is this "application"?
Working of propositional logic, using Coq just for exploration:
I cannot match the effect of apply in this code with a rule of natural deduction (*):
Lemma importation : forall p q r : Prop,
  (p -> q -> r) -> p /\ q -> r.
Proof.
  intros p q r H.
  intros [Hp Hq].
  apply H.
  - exact Hp.
  - exact Hq.
Qed.

I can see that that step is "justified": if we can prove p we can get q->r, if we can also prove q we can get r, so proving r reduces to proving p and q.
But, in terms of natural deduction, by which rule(s) can we go from (...,p->q->r,...|-r) to [(...|-p), (...|-q)]?  Otherwise, how to prove the theorem above?
(*) I am looking at Natural deduction / Gentzen-style propositional logic on WP in particular.

I cannot find a solution here either, Fitch-style: https://proofs.openlogicproject.org/ , and with an online prover I get a proof that uses negation and even some classical steps IIANM...  But the bottom line maybe is I do not find anything like "reduce a goal to residual goals" in the way these rules are presented.  Yet, the theorem above should be easily provable, shouldn't it?  I must be missing something...

You are proving Exposrtation: assume the antecedent of the conclusion, i.e. "p and q", apply Conjunction Elim followed by two times Conditional Elim (Modus Ponens) and conclude with Conditional Intro.

@MauroALLEGRANZA  Wikipedia tells me that, "strictly speaking", that is Importation, the other way round is Exportation.  See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exportation_(logic) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Import%E2%80%93export_(logic)

Correct. I've used Wiki's entry called "Exportation" concerning  both

Complementing Andrej's answer, here is the corresponding proof in natural deduction:
                  [p ^ q]¹
                  -------- (^E₁)
[p -> q -> r]²       p          [p ^ q]¹
-----------------------(->E)    --------(^E₂)
          q -> r                   q
         ---------------------------(->E)
                        r
                   ----------(->I)¹
                   p ^ q -> r
          ---------------------------(->I)²
          (p -> q -> r) -> p ^ q -> r

As you can see,

the first step in the Coq proof (intros H where H : p -> q -> r) corresponds to the last step in the ND proof (->I on p -> q -> r),
the second step in the Coq proof (intros [Hp Hq]) corresponds to the second-to-last step in the ND proof (->I on p ^ q) combined with the first two (^E),
the the third step in the Coq proof (apply H where H : p -> q -> r) corresdponds to the two third-to-last steps in the ND proof (->E q -> r after ->E on q -> q -> r).


Ah, thanks very much, now I see what you mean.  I guess I am just confused by the different "styles" and the associated names: here is a proof I was given meanwhile (reformatted to make it fit), which goes "forward" in the sense I had in mind: 0: P -> (Q -> R) (Premisse), 1: P /\ Q (Assumption), 2: P (/\E,1), 3: Q -> R (->E,0,2), 4: Q (/\E,1), 5: R (->E,3,4), 6: P /\ Q -> R (Discharge,1).

Yes, this this the equivalent linear notation (with two ->E steps summarized and the last ->I step skipped) analogous to the tree style I gave.

I'd accept both answers as solutions if I could, together they explain all I needed.  Eventually, I have decided to mark this as the one, it fleshes out the issue of "direction" I was most confused about: besides, Andrej does not need more points... :)  Thanks very much again both of you.

Lemma importation (p q r : Prop) :
  (p -> q -> r) -> p /\ q -> r.
Proof.
  intros H. (* =>-intro *)
  intros [Hp Hq]. (* =>-intro, ∧-elim₁, ∧-elim₂ *)
  apply H. (* =>-elim, =>-elim *)
  - exact Hp. (* assumption *)
  - exact Hq. (* assumption *)
Qed.

Note that:

intros [Hp Hq] first applies a $\Rightarrow$-introduction, and immediately follows with left and right $\land$-eliminations
apply H chains two $\Rightarrow$-eliminations.


Thanks very much for the step-by-step, that was most helpful.  That apply is still sort of doing it backwards re the natural deduction rules (at least in the Gentzen style), where imp-elim is more like apply in Hp, etc. (right?  Not that that is a problem of course).  Anyway, I was indeed confused especially about implication elimination.  Thanks again.

We have it "backwards" compared to ND elsewhere too - the Coq intross come first, whereas the corresponding $\to I$s in a ND derivation would be the last steps.

This is part of the general nature of the proof technique of posting goals and then showing on the following lines how to fulfill them, as opposed to natural deduction where the obtained conclusion is only written down as a new node further down in the tree once it has been established by means of its already proven premises.

Yeah, I made a typo in my last comment; it should have been $\to I$ (as written earlier) and not $\to E$. Sorry for the confusion.

Corrected version: As an addition to my first comment, these $\to I$ applications in an ND derivation would be the reverse order of what they are in the Coq proof.

I posted an answer.

@JulioDiEgidio: where things are "backwards" depends on how you read inference rules. If you read them bottom up (from conclusion towards premises), then ⇒-elimination say: in order to prove u it suffices to prove v ⇒ u and v. If you read it top-down it says: if we have v ⇒ u and v then we can make u. In Coq-style proofs such as the ones in this question, you should read the rules bottom-up, so that they tell you how to replace your goal with smaller goals.

To further complement answers, here is a toy experiment shallowly embedding (a little fragment of propositional) natural deduction in Coq's interactive proof mode. -- This quite sums up my understanding of ND at this point, especially w.r.t. the mechanics of proof assistants.  Suggestions, objections and plain nitpicking are very welcome: otherwise, I won't elaborate further.
Ltac impI :=
  match goal with
  | |- ?P -> _ =>
      let HP := fresh "H0" in
        intros HP;
        idtac "impI" P "as" HP
  end.

Ltac impE :=
  match goal with
  | H : ?P -> ?Q, HP : ?P |- _ =>
      let HQ := fresh "H0" in
        assert (HQ : Q)
          by exact (H HP);
        clear H;
        idtac "impE" H HP "as [" HQ "]"
  end.

Ltac andI :=
  match goal with
  | |- ?P /\ ?Q =>
      split;
      [ idtac "andI" P
      | idtac "andI" Q
      ]
  end.

Ltac andE :=
  match goal with
  | H : _ /\ _ |- _ =>
      let H1 := fresh "H0" in
      let H2 := fresh "H1" in
        destruct H as [H1 H2];
        idtac "andE" H "as [" H1 H2 "]"
  end.

Ltac uniE :=
  match goal with
  | HP : ?P |- ?P =>
      exact HP
  end.

Lemma import (p q r : Prop) :
  (p -> q -> r) -> p /\ q -> r.
Proof.
  impI.  (* impI (p -> q -> r) as H0 *)
  impI.  (* impI (p /\ q) as H1 *)
  andE.  (* andE H1 as [ H2 H3 ] *)
  impE.  (* impE H0 H2 as [ H1 ] *)
  impE.  (* impE H1 H3 as [ H0 ] *)
  uniE.
Qed.

Lemma andcomm (p q : Prop) :
  (p /\ q) -> q /\ p.
Proof.
  impI.  (* impI (p /\ q) as H0 *)
  andE.  (* andE H0 as [ H1 H2 ] *)
  andI.  (* andI q *) (* andI p *)
  - uniE.
  - uniE.
Qed.

One thing I should clarify: imp-elim above is still a simplification and works only if the premise is in the context, which is enough for the two little example lemmas shown, but the actual imp-elim I have to use in my (still very early stage) solver is (C,X->Y=>Z) --> [(C,Y=>Z),(C=>X)], otherwise even some very simple theorems cannot be proved: and, eventually, I can see that this rule is the imp-elim in ND.
(Should you be interested, here is the Prolog code:
https://gist.github.com/jp-diegidio/b6a7a071f9f81a469c493c4afcc5cb11
It's work in progress: thanks to you, negation next!  Anyway, I'm sure I'll have more questions in the future...)

Eventually, I have realised that what I should have been asking about all along (what I am actually doing) is Sequent Calculus, not ND.  Slowly slowly...
